# proof of logarithmic property $ a^{\log_{a}{b}}=b$

Tags: logarithms

I don't know how to show that $\displaystyle a^{\log_{a}{b}}=b$

Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: $a^x = e^{x\log a}$

Comment: That's a possible definition of $\log _ab$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle\log_ab=c$

$\displaystyle\iff a^c=b$ (from the definition of [logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.htmla))

Replace the value of $c$

Comment: OK thanks a lot now I see

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Git Gud, this is actually a **definition** of the logarithm of $b$ with base $a$.